# Knockout computed restoring old value

Tags: knockout.js

I have a jQuery dialog in which the user can switch between pages. The problem is that the view model remembers which page was displayed last — if I open the dialog, navigate to page 2 and close it, it will stay on page 2 if I reopen the dialog again.

How do I reset my view model each time it is opened?

```
JobActivity = function() {
    var self = this;

    // This is the array i am putting the data in  from ajax call 
    self.arraytoadd  = ko.observableArray();
    self.currentPage = ko.observable(1);
    self.perPage     = 5;

    self.pagedItems = ko.computed(function() {
        self.dummy();
        var pg    = this.currentPage(),
            start = this.perPage * (pg - 1),
            end   = start + this.perPage;

        return self.arraytoadd().slice(start, end);
    }, this);

    self.nextPage = function() {
        if (self.nextPageEnabled()) this.currentPage(this.currentPage() + 1);
    };

    self.previousPage = function() {
        if (this.previousPageEnabled()) this.currentPage(this.currentPage() - 1);
    };

    self.nextPageEnabled = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.arraytoadd().length > this.perPage * this.currentPage();
    }, this);

    self.previousPageEnabled = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.currentPage() > 1;
    }, this);
}
```

Comment: Please post the javascript for the open dialog. On open of the dialog you could set the currentPage back to 1.

Comment: I rewrote your question to make it easier to understand; I hope it matches your intent. Could you please add the dialogs markup and the code for the binding you use to open that dialog?

Comment: And please make a much bigger effort into making your questions understandable... When I first saw this question pop up, I wouldn't be bothered to even look at it, it made very little sense. We shouldn't have to fix up your questions to make it even remotely understandable, that's _your_ job.

Comment: Ok Jeff and janfoeh, next time i wouldnt repeat the same.Thanks again for your effort.